# how to add try and catch validation and how to fix my switch, do-while error java

Tags: java, validation, try-catch, do-while

I cant post the code in here not sure why error so i post on reddit

https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/3izvy2/how_to_add_try_and_catch_validation_and_how_to/

Comment: You need to declare `int choose` in a place where the switch can see it.  If it's outside a pair of curly braces, it can't see what's inside the braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your try/catch syntax is fine, what's the problem?

However, your do/while is wrong, I see the while is all the way down there, so remove your last curly bracket from the do and put it right before the while:

```
do{     
 try{ 

  System.out.println("Choose your option");

  System.out.println("  1. Create List of used car");
  System.out.println("  2. Print list of used car");
  System.out.println("  3. Search ");
  System.out.println("  4. Exit");

  int choose = read.nextInt();

      if ( choose <= 4){
           throw new Exception();
    }

  }catch (Exception e){
  System.out.println("Please enter input option from 1-4");

..rest of code...
}while(choose <= 4);
```

and in your switch, `choose` is not avaliable - `choose` is a local variable for the try/catch only, nothing other than the try/catch can access it. It would be best to make `choose` a global variable by putting it at the top of the do:

```
do{
    int choose;
    ..blah blah..
}
```

And reference to it without the int - just `choose`:

```
choose = read.nextInt();
```

Finally, you need a `break` at the end of every `case`, and what's the point of the `return`s?:

```
case 1:
  for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){

System.out.print("Enter Model: ");
Model = read.next();
System.out.print("Enter Plate Number: ");
PlateNo = read.next();
System.out.print("Enter Manufactured Year: ");
ManufacturedYear = read.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter Transmission Type: ");   
TransmissionType = read.next();
System.out.print("Enter Color: "); 
Color = read.next();

CarList used = new CarList(Model, PlateNo, ManufacturedYear,
       TransmissionType, Color);
a[i] = used;
        return;
}
break;

...keep on going....
```

You shouldn't rely on others to fix your simple syntax problems, don't panic when you get an error, just go through your code and learn how to debug messages!

Comment: @nabskim Does my answer work? If so, please accept my answer and upvote if you can!